# Which language use to automatize the data extraction from websites to Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, web, import, export

I would like to import data from specific websites to one or different Excel file(s).

The different websites are the following :

- https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-dow_quotes_settlements_futures.html
- https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-nasdaq-100_quotes_settlements_futures.html
- https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/market-data/statistics/market-statistics-online/100!onlineStats?productGroupId=13394&productId=34642&viewType=4&busDate=20191018  (I didn't find any direct link, please change the part at the end of the link with the current date !)
- https://live.euronext.com/fr/product/index-futures/FCE-DPAR/settlement-prices

Each day, the websites give, for each contracts (DEC19, MAR20, JUN20 etc) some values (open, high, low, last, settle, volume etc.)

I would like to automaticaly extract/copy/import (in an .csv or Excel file for example), everyday, for each product (DOW, NASDAQ, CAC and DAX) and only for the contract which has the highest volume, the values.

Somebody told me it could be done by using C# language.. However I have absolutely no knowledge in C#.

I've also tried to use Excel and the function Data>Import data from a website, however the "table" is empty, maybe they protected their data ?! (I wanted to create a macro in Excel to automatize this process but it didn't work).

So the main question is : which language will allow me to automatize the data extraction from these websites to excel ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Possibly every sensible language can be used for this. Just pick the one that suites you best (the one you are familiar with). 
I'd use Python (requests with BeautifulSoup) to do this personally.

If you don't want to code, a visual program like KNIME could be useful for this as well.

Some example code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://webscraper.io/test-sites/tables'
req = requests.get(url, verify=False)
html = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
df = pd.read_html(str(html))[0]
df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

This will give you the first table of that page and export it as csv
read up on documentation (and StackOverflow ;)) on BeautifulSoup on how to select/find/get the elements you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the end, I'd like to put  all the files on a cloud and that it all automatically works on its own. So I guess KNIME isn't a solution. I'll check for Python and BeautifulSoup, however I have no experience yet with Python ^^

Comment: added an example code snippet.

Comment: So I've installed Python 3.8. Then I've created a .txt file on my desktop. I've put your code in it. (I've just changed the URL). Then I've renamed the .txt file to a .py file. And I ran it. Nothing happend.. I expected  to have a .csv file on my desktop. Am I completely wrong ?

Comment: I would expect you to get some errors because you need to 'pip install pandas' for instance.. ;) 
I'm using PyCharm, might be useful

Comment: I've opened cmd on Windows. I wrote 'py -3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4' + enter. Then I wrote 'py -3 -m pip install pandas' + enter. Then I wrote "py -3 -m pip install requests'.  Now I run again .py file with your code in it. Now a cmd (py.exe) Windows pops up stays 1 second and disappears. The following error is displayed : insecure request warning unverified request http is being made. Couldn't find a tree builder with the feature you requested lxml.

Comment: ah yes.. pip install lxml as well

Comment: and add a print statement so you can do some logging (print(df)

Comment: Okay now it's working for the website Eurexchange.com. I have a CSV file created with the wanted values. However, for the 2 websites cmegroup.com the program also creates a CSV file but no values are there. And concerning the website Euronext, the CSV file is even not created... Any idea ?! Thank you very much